# Focus to entry of collectionview at specific index

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a ordering solution.
I have a collectionView that is bound to a List.
The datatemplate of the collectionview is created at runtime.
Inside the datatemplate i have a Entry.
I make a call to a webservice and i get a Item.

Before I insert the Item inside the list i make a linq search and if the Item does not exist in the list I insert it to it.
So far so good.
But when the linq search returns a line, i want somehow to focus at the entry, so i can change the text (it as a qty field) of it.[image]

My code as simple as i can make it:

```
public class IteLinesViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<IteLine> IteLines { get; set; }
}


public class IteLine : ExtendedBindableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private string _Name;
     public string Name
     {
         get => _Name;
         set => SetProperty(ref _Name, value);
     }
     
     private double _qty;
     public double Qty
     {
         get => _qty;
         set => SetProperty(ref _qty, value);
     }
}

CollectionView4Lines.ItemTemplate = CreateItemTemplate();

private DataTemplate CreateItemTemplate()
{
    return new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        Grid OuterGrid = new Grid() { Margin = 0, Padding = 0 };
        OuterGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Star });
        OuterGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = 65 });
        
        Label MainDisplayLabel = new Label() { TextType = TextType.Html, FontSize = 18 };
        MainDisplayLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
        OuterGrid.Children.Add(MainDisplayLabel, 0, 0);

        Entry qtyEntry = new Entry();
        qtyEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty,"Qty")
        OuterGrid.Children.Add(qtyEntry, 1, 0);
        
        return OuterGrid;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation to your class

```
public class IteLine : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _qty;
    public string Qty
   {
         get {return _qty;}
         set 
         {
             _qty= value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Qty");
         }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Now, if you find the index where you want to change it. You can do it like this

```
IteLines[linkqIndex].Qty = 5;
```

Comment: I have the OnPropertyChanged, i forgot to paste it on the question.
You are saying to modify the Qty. What i want is to focus at the Entry, so the user can insert the qty he desires

Comment: Please try the ScrollTo method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.scrollto?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: The ScrollTo  method will scroll to the desired line, but will not focus the Entry

Comment: I am thinking to create a Entry property in the Iteline class. Then try something like IteLines[linkqIndex].EntryQty.Focus(). My problem is that i do not know how to set value to the EntrQty. The CreateItemTemplate() must somehow update the Itelines in order to set the EntryQty of each line

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811089/focus-viewcell-entry-on-listview-item-selection this link helps you to bind the Entry but call the Focus() onitemselected

Comment: The link was a saver. A bit unorthodox but it did the trick. Thanks a lot